# Responsive scaling not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a short one-page site with a rotating set of pix. Somehow the js script and images are breaking the site's ability to scale down. I'm not an experienced coder, so I'm flailing a bit.

I'm pretty sure it's to do with some of the fixed widths in the CSS, but removing them creates even more trouble. Any help tracking down the cause would be much appreciated. Here's a [Codepen link to the problem](https://codepen.io/Dutchg/pen/KBWpyO).

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" ; charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="created" content="Fri, 22 Jan 2016 17:43:40 GMT" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="jvs_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="maingrid">
      <div class="slides">
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out1.png" max-width:100%;>
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out2.png" max-width:100%;>
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out3.png">
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out4.png">
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out5.png">
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out6.png">
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out7.png">
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out8.png">
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out9.png">
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/slideshow_images/out10.png">
      </div>
      <!-- end of slides div -->
      <div class="centertext">
        <img src="http://tests.markgarvey.com/images/JVSA_weblogo3.png" width="281" height="106" alt="" title="" border="0" />
        <p class="name">FIRSTNAME LASTNAME</p>
        <p class="address">1234 Example Street<br> Princeton, New Jersey 12345<br> testing@email.net
          <br> 505.422.6563
        </p>
        <p>Solemnly he came forward and mounted the round gunrest. He faced about and blessed gravely thrice the tower, the surrounding country and the awaking mountains. Then, catching sight of Stephen Dedalus, he bent towards him and made rapid crosses
          in the air, gurgling in his throat and shaking his head. Stephen Dedalus, displeased and sleepy, leaned his arms on the top of the staircase and looked coldly at the shaking gurgling face that blessed him, equine in its length, and at the light
          untonsured hair, grained and hued like pale oak.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- end of centertext div -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of maingrid div -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of wrap div -->
  <script>
    function nextSlide() {
      var q = function(sel) {
        return document.querySelector(sel);
      }
      q(".slides").appendChild(q(".slides img:first-child"));
    }
    setInterval(nextSlide, 5000)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.maingrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.centertext {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 20px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.name {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.address {
  margin-top: 8px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 19px;
}

/* the slide container with a fixed size */
.slides {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 670px;
  position: relative;
}

/* the images are positioned absolutely to stack. opacity transitions are animated. */
.slides img {
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

/* the first image is the current slide. it's faded in. */
.slides img:first-child {
  z-index: 2;
  /* frontmost */
  opacity: 1;
}

/* the last image is the previous slide. it's behind the current slide and it's faded over. */
.slides img:last-child {
  z-index: 1;
  /* behind current slide */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *fixed widths* (of 1000px) are to blame.

Try:

```
.slides {
  width:100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 670px;
  position: relative;
}

/* the images are positioned absolutely to stack. opacity transitions are animated. */
.slides img { 
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-bottom:60px;
}
```

Here is an **[edited codepen](https://codepen.io/Ajax28/pen/PBpyje)**.